# Icon in Muzei Source Selector appears to not be scaling properly

Tags: android, muzei

I'm not sure what goes on under the hood in Muzei.

I have assets for

```
mdpi (48x48)
hdpi (72x72)
xhdpi (96x96)
xxhdpi (144x144)
xxxhdpi (192x192)
nodpi (512x512)
```

I've followed the [example source's](https://github.com/romannurik/muzei/tree/master/example-source-500px) folder/asset structure to the T, but, when Muzei loads my source, it fills the entire selector circle with the icon instead of centring it nicely in the middle with ample padding like the defaults (see below).

My Manifest is basically:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <service
        android:name=".UnsplashForMuzeiRemoteArtSource"
        android:description="@string/source_description"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/source_name" >
        ...
    </service>
</application>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Muzei doesn't do anything to the icon, just displays it without scaling or padding.

What I did to fix it is just added padding to the PNG (to my base SVG and re-converted it).